# Is it possible to have a fixed SKSpriteNode on two scenes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is it possible to have an SKSpriteNode that is essentially above the scene, in a fixed position? Almost like the way you have something with a fixed position on an HTML document. I want to have an `SKSpriteNode` stay in the same position even when the scene changes, but I'm not sure if its possible.

This is the code for the SKSpriteNode:

```
    SKSpriteNode *kitty = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Kitty.png"] size:CGSizeMake(82.6, 146.4)];
    kitty.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    kitty.zPosition = 1.0;

    [self addChild:kitty];
```

And I want it to stay in the middle of the screen as I transition to the next screen. This is the transition for the second screen:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"play"]) {

        scene1 *subMenu = [[scene1 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:subMenu transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionUp duration:2.0]];
    }

}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? If not please let me know and spare me the time of continuing to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All nodes belong to only one scene. If you dismiss the scene, all of its nodes will be dismissed as well. You could consider using your chosen image as you dismiss the old scene and start the new scene with the same image.

If you use `fadeWithDuration:` and set the time interval to almost zero, it might just appear as a very fast flicker in your image. Provided of course that your next scene has the same image ready to display at the start.